# Azure SQL Data Sync: Can you set up a sync that does not replicate deletes?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I want to have 2 Azure Databases. One will act as an exact replica of an offsite database. That database will regularly purge data that becomes stale.

I would like to have a second database (i.e. Archive Database) which replicates the all Inserts and Updates that happen in the first database but does not replicate the DELETE transactions since I would like to continue to have an archive of those records.

Is Azure Data Sync the right solution to facilitate this and does it provide a way to perform a one way sync that excludes DELETE transactions? If not is this something that can be facilitated in another way (i.e. A complete one way sync with DELETE permission on that database table omitted)

Answer (score 0):

Data Sync will not work for this scenario.

You might be able to use temporal tables and it's historical data retention functionality linked below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-temporal-tables

Have you considered taking point in time restores of the database before the deletes?

Josh